# Autofac. Base Class properties resolved without specific injection

Tags: c#, dependencies, inversion-of-control, autofac, code-injection

I'm looking for a possible solution to the following.

I have a base class that has a dependency which I currently use property injection to satisfy.

```
public class BaseClass {
    IService SomeService { get; set; }
}
```

I have multiple classes which inherit from this base class.

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass, IDerivedClass {

}
```

And I inject using the following.

```
builder.RegisterType<DerivedClass>().As<IDerivedClass>().OnActivated(e => e.Instance.SomeService = e.Context.Resolve<IService>());
```

I do this for about 12 other classes which extend the base class. Is there a way so that any class extending BaseClass will get my IService registration without setting up an Activation event for each registration? It's working fine like this, but would just like to clean up the registrations.

Answer (score 1):

Just use constructor injection. Create constructor with parameters for your class like

```
public DerivedClass(IServiceOne service1, IService2 service2)
{
this._service1 = service1;
this._service2 = service2;

}
```

and make autofac doing his job automatically, like

```
builder.RegisterType<T>();
```

Comment: I guess I should expand. I have a circular reference, hence the OnActivated. (the circular reference makes sense). I guess what I meant was, I want the OnActivated to apply to all sub-classes on BaseClass without writing the OnActivated for each registration. (The IService is a Singleton, that also references all the registered IDerivedClasses).It works fine with the OnActivated, just wanted to clean it up.

Comment: Actually i could be wrong, but if you have circular dependency on singleton - it's 99.9% probability that you made a mistake when designing this component. And about your problem, if it's still actual for you I will take a look on that through the couple of days, very busy now

Answer (score 0):

Ten years later now you can use the `required` property to enable auto injection without parameters in constructor: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html#required-properties